# DialogFragment appears on top of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment, android-actionbar-compat

I have an ActionBar in my app (via the v7 compat library) and it works just fine. When I bring up a DialogFragment though, the overflow menu appears **behind** the dialog. I was expecting the ActionBar to always be on top. Needless to say, this disrupts input into the ActionBar.

Here's the code to display the fragment - pretty standard stuff

```
CChildDialog dlg = createDialog(id,args);
                if (dlg != null) {
                    // now display the fragment!

                    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
                    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
                    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(dialogTag);
                    if (prev != null) {
                        ft.remove(prev);
                    }
                    // Create and show the dialog.
                    dlg.show(ft, dialogTag);
                }
```

My dialog class doesn't do anything weird other than enable background clicks like so:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Window dialogWindow = getDialog().getWindow();

        // Make the dialog possible to be outside touch
        dialogWindow.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }
```

[image: Screen Capture]

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, your dialog class does very weird things. You turn off the flags that make it a dialog.

The dialog appears on top of your activity (which includes your actionbar) therefore it is normal that a menu in your actionbar appears behind the dialog window. You have turned off the modal nature of the dialog otherwise you would not be able to activate the menu.

Comment: If I remove those flags on `onViewCreated,` I am unable to interact with the ActionBar entirely

Comment: That is the point of a dialog window. It holds the focus until you do something with it. Your UI will be confusing and non standard if you do what you are currently doing. You need to rethink this.

Comment: I'm really going for a modeless dialog approach here, so I'll go investigate `PopupWindow` to see if it behaves as I'm expecting